# Does CnosQL support IN operator?

Tags: sql, cnosdb

In CnosQL (the quasi-SQL for [CnosDB](https://github.com/cnosdb/cnosdb)), if I filter the results, I have to use OR, which is verbose:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE region = 'ny' OR region = 'ln' OR region = 'hk' OR region = 'sh'
```

Any better idea?

Comment: There is no database nor language named "CnosQL". Please clarify exactly what software you're using.

Comment: thx for the feedback. just updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

CnosDB doesn't support using the `OR` operator in the WHERE clause to specify multiple time intervals and tag values.

But you can separate multiple SELECT statements in a query with a semicolon (`;`).

Try with:

```
SELECT_clause WHERE_clause;SELECT_clause WHERE_clause
```

For example:

```
SELECT "temperature" FROM "air" WHERE "station"='LianYunGang';SELECT "temperature" FROM "air" WHERE "station"='XiaoMaiDao'
```

Comment: Looks like the IN is supported now ;) see https://github.com/cnosdb/cnosdb/pull/322 and https://github.com/cnosdb/cnosdb/pull/321. Any ETA?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that.

Comment: not at all. I am wondering when this feature will be ready. I mean, which release?